# Indent non-preprocessor code between #if and #endif with clang-format

Tags: c, formatting, clang-format

I'm currently trying to set up a `.clang-format` file for a project, and was wondering if there's a combination of settings to auto-indent not just preprocessor directives but also code enclosed by them.

As an example, I'd want the snippet

```c
void foo()
{
  #ifdef FOO
  bar1();
  #else
  bar2();
  #endif
}
```

to be formatted as

```c
void foo()
{
  #ifdef FOO
    bar1();
  #else
    bar2();
  #endif
}
```

I haven't seen an option that explicitly performs this indentation, but this is also my very first time using clang-format, so I don't know its intricacies.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why would someone need smth like that (conceptually it seems wrong to me). Those examples are too trivial but mixing preprocessor directives indenting with statements (*if*, *for*, ...) indenting might yield very misleading and ugly looking code.

Comment: Probably not universal, but in the code styles I am familiar with the preprocessor directives aren't being indented, and the code between them is indented just like it would without the directives.

Comment: @CristiFati the problem is that this is a big, already established code base with existing style guides, but nothing is automated (it's basically a case of "before something gets merged it lands on someone's desk who then manually verifies the style"). There are definitely some peculiar style choices in there, but I don't have the pull to change any of them and the worry is that the effort to automate the formatting will be rejected if I don't manage to reproduce the existing style